# Shiny does not show the tables

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a shiny app and I have a problem while I want it to return two tables (or sometimes plots) with the same codes and different input values. Here is a sample of codes. If you run the codes you can see it just returns one of the tables.

```
library(shiny)
library("strucchange")
require(partykit)

airq <- subset(airquality,!is.na(Ozone))

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarPanel(
  selectInput(
    "max",
    label = "depth",
    choices = list("2" = "2", "3" = "3", "4" = "4"),
    selected = list("3")
   
  ),
  
  selectInput(
    "max2",
    label = "depth2",
    choices = list("2" = "2", "3" = "3", "4" = "4"),

  )),
  
  
  
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("myTable", uiOutput("myTable"))
    ,
    tabPanel("myTable2", uiOutput("myTable2"))
  )))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  fit1 <- reactive({
    ctree(Ozone ~ .,
          data = airq,
          control=ctree_control(maxdepth =input$max))
  })
  fit2 <- reactive({
    ctree(Ozone ~ .,
          data = airq,
          control=ctree_control(maxdepth = input$max2))
  })
 output$myTable = renderUI({
    test1 <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(sctest(fit1())))
    {test <- sctest(fit1())[i]
    if(nrow(as.data.frame(test))!=0)
      test1[[length(test1)+1]] <- test} 
    names <- c()
    for(i in 1:length(test1)){
      names[i] <- paste0('name', i)
    }
    names(test1) <- names
    lapply(names(test1), function(x) {
      output[[x]] = DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(data.frame(test1[[x]])) 
      })
    })
    
    return(lapply(names(test1), DT::dataTableOutput))
  })
  output$myTable2 = renderUI({
    test1 <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(sctest(fit2())))
    {test <- sctest(fit2())[i]
    if(nrow(as.data.frame(test))!=0)
      test1[[length(test1)+1]] <- test} 
    names <- c()
    for(i in 1:length(test1)){
      names[i] <- paste0('name', i)
    }
    names(test1) <- names
    lapply(names(test1), function(x) {
      output[[x]] = DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(data.frame(test1[[x]])) 
      })
    })
    
    return(lapply(names(test1), DT::dataTableOutput))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Shiny does not return any error but I can not see the tables (sometimes it shows one of the tables).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems with your code;

1. You are missing `tabsetPanel` in here, where it should be:

   ```
    mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("myTable", uiOutput("myTable"))
    ,
    tabPanel("myTable2", uiOutput("myTable2"))
    )))
   ```
2. If you are generating datatables, then the rendering functions should be `renderDataTable` instead of `renderTable`

I'm not sure what is exactly what you are trying to do here, but if you want to show a dynamic number of datatables then each one of them needs space in the UI. Here is an example on how to do that; using `renderUI`.

https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-app-with-dynamic-number-of-datatables/2405/2

**EDIT:**

After your corrections from suggestions above, the problem is clear: outputs need to have unique names. Change the naming of the second set of tables (something like `names[i] <- paste0('name_', i)` and you will see the problem resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions! I actually tried it but it did not solve the problem. It still does not show the tables in the output@David Jorquera

Comment: Try to run your code outside shiny. `names(test1)` inside `lapply` gives NULL. Its not clear what you are trying to pull off here, so it's difficult to help you.

Comment: I fix my codes and edit them here! Sorry for that. Now you can see that it just returns one of the tables. @ David Jorquera